# Is there a way to run 2to3 with pip install?

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt, python-2to3

I'm trying to maintain dependencies using `pip install -r requirements.txt`. However, some of required packages do not support Python 3 directly, but can be converted manually using `2to3`.

Is there a way to force `pip` to run `2to3` on those packages automagically when doing `pip install -r requirements.txt`?

Comment: When you say "converted manually" - does that actually mean, `2to3` can be run on them, and convert them successfully without manual tweaking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it needs to be part of the package setup configuration instead. See [Supporting both Python 2 and 3 with Distribute](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/python3.html).

You add metadata to your package installer:

```
setup(
    name='your.module',
    version = '1.0',
    description='This is your awesome module',
    author='You',
    author_email='your@email',
    package_dir = {'': 'src'},
    packages = ['your', 'your.module'],
    test_suite = 'your.module.tests',
    use_2to3 = True,
    convert_2to3_doctests = ['src/your/module/README.txt'],
    use_2to3_fixers = ['your.fixers'],
    use_2to3_exclude_fixers = ['lib2to3.fixes.fix_import'],
)
```

Such a package would then automatically run `2to3` on installation into a Python 3 system.

`2to3` is a tool, not a magic bullet, you cannot apply it to an arbitrary package `pip` downloads from PyPI. The package needs to support it in the way it is coded. Thus, running it automatically from `pip` is not going to work; the responsibility lies with the package maintainer.

Note that just because `2to3` runs successfully on a package, it does not necessarily follow the package will work in Python 3. Assumptions about bytes vs. unicode usually crop up when you actually start using the package.

Contact the maintainers of the packages you are interested in and ask what the status is for that package for Python 3. Supplying patches to them usually helps. If such requests and offers for help fall on deaf ears, for Open Source packages you can always fork them and apply the necessary changes yourself.

Comment: @Jon: You may want to propose that edit to the Distribute project; that sample code was coded verbatim from the distribute documentation. :-)

Comment: I saw that - but it bugged me - I'll add it to my list of documentation to be going through ;)